# probability that pseudo random numbers from cyclic group not in subset

Tags: probability

Suppose we chose $a, b$ from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for prime p uniformly and randomly. Now for some $t$, let $r_i = ai + b$ mod $p$, for $1 \leq i \leq t$. Let $c \in [0, 1]$. I want to show that there is a subset $S \subset \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $|S| \geq cp$ and the probability that none of the $r_i$ are in $S$ is at least $\frac{(1 -c)^2}{4t}$.

I know that $r_i, r_j$ are pairwise independent and that each $r_i$ is uniformly distributed over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. My thought is to define some variable and use Chebyshev inequality to bound it. Initially I tried sample randomly and defined $X = \sum_{i = 1}^{cn} X_i$ where each $X_i$ is 1 if the i^th sample is one of the $r_i$, but this does not take into account repeat samples. My thought is maybe to define $X$ as some variant of the coupon collector problem where you have $t$ forbidden coupons and the process stops once you pick one of these forbidden coupons, but I'm not sure if this is valid or the best way.

Comment: I'll use $X=\sum_{j=1}^{cp} X_j$ to disambiguate notation. What if you define $X_j$ to be the number of $i$ such that $r_i=j$, rather than just equal to the sign of that quantity ($1$ or $0$)? Then repeat samples are simply counted, but we still want to detect the event $X=0$.

Comment: since $Pr(r_i = j) = \frac{1}{p} \forall j$, would this make $X_j \sim Binom(t, 1/p)$?

Comment: Not quite because $\{r_i=j\colon 1\le i\le t\}$ are not independent events. Most of the time (when $a\ne0$), only one $r_i$ can equal $j$, and that happens with probability $\frac tp$. When $a=0$, we have $X_j = t$ with probability $\frac1p$ and $0$ with probability $1-\frac1p$.

Comment: Fwiw: asked and answered here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/53866/13319